# code to insert date and day as yyyy-mm-dd Ddd

Tags: date, autokey

Objective: with a shortcut, e.g. alt+d, insert

```
yyyy-mm-dd Ddd
```

Example of Ddd: `Mon`

I have the following code for an Autokey script

```
from datetime import datetime
keyboard.send_keys(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

That only gives me the date.

How should I expand the script to get the 3 character day too?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior  then use %a in the format string: e.g. datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %a')

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: @Steve: many thanks for the link to the page, and for your advice to add %a - that works !

Comment: @Bsquare: thank you for edit. When I drew up my question, the automatic evaluation rejected it on the basis of the title, because it was not clear enough. That surprised me a bit because I thought it was clear. Nevertheless, I "upgraded" it and it was accepted. Obviously, what a newbie author thinks is clear isn't necessarily so. I'll do my best to learn & improve.

Comment: @Steve idea: you may please write your comment as a answer? so this question is listened wit answer

Answer (score 0):

See [docs.python.org/2/library/…](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) then use %a in the format string: e.g. datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %a')